# Filtering the distinct rows from Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with two columns schema as:

```
ID1,ID2
```

Values are as:

```
x y
y x
a b
b a
```

I just want resultset  as a whole like:

```
x y 
a b
```

I want to remove duplicate

Need the sql query for the same.

Comment: please also add what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, I have answered this in the past in DBA community. Please see if this is what you needed: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/89199/52567

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to achieve this is to use `LEFT JOIN` like this.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a9e50/2)

**Query**

```
SELECT T1.ID1,T1.ID2 
FROM YourTable T1
LEFT JOIN YourTable T2
ON T1.ID1 = T2.ID2
AND T1.ID2 = T2.ID1
AND T2.ID1 < T2.ID2
WHERE T2.ID1 IS NULL
```

**Output**

```
| ID1 | ID2 |
|-----|-----|
|   x |   y |
|   a |   b |
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `EXISTS` like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM yourTable ti
                 WHERE t.ID1 = ti.ID2 AND t.ID2 = ti.ID1
                   AND ti.ID1 > ti.ID2)
```